# How to get current object in component (symfony 1.4)?

Tags: php, symfony1, symfony-1.4

The only code i found is:

```
class modulenameComponents extends sfComponents
{

  public function executeAction(sfWebRequest $request)
  {

    $object = $this->getContext()->getController()
      ->getAction($this->getModuleName(), $request->getParameter('action'))
      ->getRoute()->getObject();

  } 
}
```

But it doesn't work if component includes in different module.

Answer (score 3):

The component is called from the template, so pass your object from the template:

```
<?php include_component('modulename', 'actionName', array('myObject' => $myObject)) ?>
```

You will be able to access your object in your component via $this:

```
class modulenameComponents extends sfComponents
{
   public function executeActionName()
   {
     // your object
     $object = $this->myObject;
     ...
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Regarding Symfony 1.4.x doctrine admin generator where everything is done in generator.yml, components receive the form object, which contains the model object. So, to get a hold of the current model object, do the following:

```
$myModelObject = $this->form->getObject();
```

NOTE: This is the model object, not the table object. To get the table object, do this:

```
$myModelTableObject = $this->form->getObject()->getTable();
```

I had to figure this out myself, so hope it helps someone...

Answer (score 0):

There may be a better way, but using `sfConfig::set()` in your action an `sfConfig::get()` in your component should do the trick.